# How do I find out what the error is on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

On localhost my app works well even when I run it in production:

```
rails s -e production
```

However on heroku it crashes. Previously it worked. I can't find the reason because "heroku logs" doesn't show much it info, it basically says "error". What kind of error? Where exactly?

Here's my gemfile:

```
ruby '2.2.1'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier' 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

We use [**LogEntries**](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries) in Heroku.

They have a really good feature called "Live Tail" - allowing you to see how the server runs in real time. This gives you verbose access to all the errors etc (*much* better than Heroku logs):

[image]

It's totally free and allows you to monitor your dyno in "real time"; it shows the actual Rails errors too.

Comment: and it shows the same thing as heroku logs, not helpfull

Comment: Showing what it says would be helpful, a screenshot will do thanks.

Comment: although, I think it does show something more, thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, please show the log that you see (possibly a screenshot)